# What is the best approach to solve the following non linear equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

Solving an electronic circuit I have come up with the following non-linear equation system, where to ease the reading, I will work with the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$ instead of circuit parameters, besides I do know that both variables $x$ and $y$ are independant from each other.

$$\tag{1}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y^2*x^2*a_1 + y^2*x^3*a_2 - y*x*a_3+x^2*a_4+x^3a_5 = 0 \\
y^2*x^2*b_1 + y^2*x^3*b_2 + x^3*b_3 + x^2*b_4+x*b5 = 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I see that the trivial solution is $x=0$, so if I simplify both by dividing by $x$ and I re-arrange it a bit, I get $(2)$ system

$$\tag{2}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y^2*x*a_1 + y^2*x^2*a_2 + x^2*a_5  + x*a_4 - y*a_3 = 0 \\
y^2*x*b_1 + y^2*x^2*b_2 + x^3*b_3 + x^2*b_4+b5 = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

So, I was wondering what would be the best approach to solve the equation system $(2)$? My first thought was an iterative process like `trust region`. But I was wondering what other approaches could be tackled. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit: I see that I made a mistake when simplifying in $x$ on the second equaion of $(1)$, the system should be
$$\tag{2}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y^2*x*a_1 + y^2*x^2*a_2 + x^2*a_5  + x*a_4 - y*a_3 = 0 \\
y^2*x*b_1 + y^2*x^2*b_2 + x^2*b_3 + x*b_4+b5 = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you discard the trivial $x=0$,from the equations you wrote, write them as
$$y^2 x a_1 + y^2 x^2 a_2 + x^2 a_5  + x a_4 = y a_3 \tag 1$$
$$y^2 x b_1 + y^2 x^2 b_2 + x^3 b_3 + x^2 b_4+b_5 = 0\tag 2$$
Extract $y^2$ from $(2)$ to get 
$$y^2=-\frac{x^3 b_3 + x^2 b_4+b_5 } {x b_1 + x^2 b_2 }\tag 3$$ and rewrite $(1)$ as
$$(y^2 x a_1 + y^2 x^2 a_2 + x^2 a_5  + x a_4)^2- y^2 a^2_3=0 \tag 4$$
Plug $(3)$ in $(4)$.

Assuming that $(b_1+x b_2)\neq 0$, you end with a polynomial of degree $4$ in $x$

$$a_3^2 b_5+x \left(a_3^2 b_4-a_1 b_5\right)+x^2 \left(a_3^2 b_3+a_4
   b_1-a_1 b_4-a_2 b_5\right)+$$ $$x^3 (a_5 b_1+a_4 b_2-a_1 b_3-a_2
   b_4)+x^4 (a_5 b_2-a_2 b_3)=0$$ Compute the roots $x_i$; but the squaring process introduced extraneous solutions. You need to discard all of those which would not make $y^2$ (as given by $(3)$) positive.

So, you have the appropriate $x$'s and the corresponding $y$'s.

**Edit**

After your mofifications, consider you last equations as
$$y^2 x a_1 + y^2 x^2 a_2 + x^2 a_5  + x a_4 = y a_3 \tag 5 $$
$$y^2 x b_1 + y^2 x^2*b_2 + x^2 b_3 + x b_4+b_5 = 0 \tag 6$$ and, for time being, let $z=y^2$ to make
$$z x a_1 + z x^2 a_2 + x^2 a_5  + x a_4 = y a_3 \tag 7 $$
$$z x b_1 + z x^2*b_2 + x^2 b_3 + x b_4+b_5 = 0 \tag 8$$
From $(8)$
$$z=-\frac{b_3 x^2+b_4 x+b_5}{x(b_1+b_2 x)}\tag 9$$ which was already $(3)$.

Now,we have (rewriting $(7)$)
$$zx( a_1+ a_2 x)+x(a_4+a_5x)=a_3 y$$ and squaring
$$\color{blue}{x^2\big(z( a_1+ a_2 x)+(a_4+a_5x)\big)^2=a_2^2 z} \tag {10}$$ where $z$ is given by $(9)$.

I strongly recommend to avoid any expansion of $(10)$; this would lead to an almost impraticable polynomial equation in $x$ of very high degree (probably $7$) with messy coefficients.

Keep the equation as it is and apply a solver

Comment: Hello @Claude could you develop a bit more the steps after plugging (3) into (4)? I get into the polynomial of degreeo 4 which is squared in one side but in the other side I still have a term depending on $a_3$ and $x$